# Changing return value of a function by parameter

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it's possible to alter the return value of a function, i.e:

```
var foo = function(options) {
  var options = options || {},
      bar = options.bar || "bar",
      baz = options.baz || "baz";

  return {
    bar: bar,
    baz: baz
  }
};
```

I would like to call it like this:

```
foo({
  bar: this.bar + "ret"
});
```

And my expectation is:

```
>>> { bar: "barret", baz: "baz" }
```

But I get this instead:

```
>>> { bar: "undefinedret", baz: "baz" }
```

How do we do that?

Comment: `this` does not work like you expect. Please, refer to (this)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword] question. `var obj = foo(); obj.bar += "ret";`

Comment: What you expect `this` is in the function call `bar: this.bar + "ret"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a scoping issue. The `this` isn't referring to the scope of `foo`.

This works:

```
foo({
  bar: foo().bar + "ret"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside function body, `this` isn't available, so your example fails. You could call:

```
foo({
    bar: "barret"
});
```

or (if you do not want to use default value outside of function):

```
var x = foo();
x.bar += "ret";
```

or change your function adding one more parameter:

```
var foo = function(options) {
  var options = options || {},
      bar = options.bar || "bar",
      baz = options.baz || "baz",
      barSuffix = options.barSuffix || "";

  return {
    bar: bar + barSuffix,
    baz: baz
  }
};

foo({barSuffix: "ret"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the result must occur inside the function, and not while passing the parameters..
(*you do not have access to the function internals while creating the parameters to pass*)

```
var foo = function(options) {
  var options = options || {},
      bar = "bar" + (options.bar || ''),
      baz = "baz" + (options.baz || '');

  return {
    bar: bar,
    baz: baz
  }
};
```

And calling it like

```
foo({
  bar: "ret"
});
```

would yield

```
>>> { bar: "barret", baz: "baz" }
```